# Is it good Practice to start service every 15 minute & destroy it after sending location information in android?

Tags: android, service, location

I wanted to send location information every 15miutes through service. The problem i faced it, the service get killed once after few hours. So, What am i  thinking is to send location information & stop the service & Create it once again after a 15minutes. is it good idea to do that? How it can be accomplished? How it can be accomplished , i don't know exactly how to stop & create service every 15 minutes.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with help of AlarmManager, Reschedule Alarm every time after it invokes that is the best way, as per your scenario. AlarmManager is never killed because it directly connected with System RTC. [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html) is the sample example.

Comment: Thanks.. Yuvi.. it gives an example of setting an alarm manager from activity. I have no activity. So how can i achieve this function from within the service?

Comment: you can use it within service also

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can use Timer and TimerTask in a Service. Here are some examples

[Android - Controlling a task with Timer and TimerTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161750/android-controlling-a-task-with-timer-and-timertask)

[Pausing/stopping and starting/resuming Java TimerTask continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098642/pausing-stopping-and-starting-resuming-java-timertask-continuously)

[Android Timer within a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819676/android-timer-within-a-service)