# TimerTask working only when button clicked, not at specified time

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a task at specific time and start the TimerTask for the first time on a button click. When the button is clicked, after first time the `system.out` should be printed everyday at a time. But it works only when button is clicked and not at specified time.

This is the activity in which I set button to start timer.

```
showViewReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Alarm alarm = new Alarm();

        }
    });
```

The class with timer:

```
public class Alarm {
Timer _timer;
Context context;
public Alarm() {

    // Create a Date corresponding to 10:30:00 AM today.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    this.context = context;
    Date alarmTime = calendar.getTime();

    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.schedule(new AlarmTask(), alarmTime);
}

class AlarmTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("*************Ok Alarm****************************");

       // _timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need to use background services!

Comment: @NiravRanpara. Like this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819676/android-timer-within-a-service

Comment: @NiravRanpara. thanks it worked. should i delete the question?

Comment: @NiravRanpara . I changed the time of my phone back to the time in which I set for the task to run, it didnt show the second time!