# Android Chronometer always resets to 00:00

Tags: android, chronometer

In an app I'm working on I need to have a timer that tracks the time from the first login until a certain goal is met. For the timer I have been using a Chronometer.

My problem is that the timer will reset if the user force-closes the app from their background apps. I need the timer to persist and update even if the app is force-closed by the user.

Currently, my code looks as follows:

```
            try{
            FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput(timerFilename);
            InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] timeInputBuffer = new char[HomeScreen.READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            t="";
            int timeCharRead;

            while((timeCharRead = InputRead.read(timeInputBuffer))> 0){
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(timeInputBuffer, 0, timeCharRead);
                t += readString;
            }
            InputRead.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 if(t == null) {
        try {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mChronometer.start();
            FileOutputStream fileout = openFileOutput(timerFilename, MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
            outputWriter.write(Long.toString(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()));
            outputWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - Long.parseLong(t);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        mChronometer.setBase(currentTime);
        mChronometer.setText(sdf.format(new Date(currentTime)));
        mChronometer.start();
    }
```

I have omitted some unrelated code for brevity.

The main issue is that after supplying the `currentTime` long to `mChronometer.setBase()` and then calling `mChronometer.start()` the timer seems to be completely random and not start where I want it to.

I understand from researching online that calling setBase() and start() will still cause the timer to start counting from 00:00 but I was under the impression that calling `mChronometer.setText()` should solve that problem, which it is not.

So my question, how can I keep the timer on-time even if the app is forcibly closed?

Answer (score 0):

From developer.android.com

> A service is a component that runs in the background to perform
>   long-running operations or to perform work for remote processes. A
>   service does not provide a user interface. For example, a service
>   might play music in the background while the user is in a different
>   application, or it might fetch data over the network without blocking
>   user interaction with an activity. Another component, such as an
>   activity, can start the service and let it run or bind to it in order
>   to interact with it. A service is implemented as a subclass of Service
>   and you can learn more about it in the Services developer guide.

So, as long as you create a service, and the user exits your app it will still run. Just like the example above.

This should give you all the information you need:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32028234) for a example on how to implement a countdown timer that runs in a service.

---

**EDIT:**

`Chronometer`is a UI widget (actually a `TextView`) in Android. So, you can't use it for non-UI purposes. Try to use `Timer` or `CountDownTimer` instead.

See this for an example usage of `Timer` inside `Service`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819721/5250273

Comment: I've attempted to implement it via a service however I'm still facing the same problem of the timer resetting once the app is force-closed and re-opened. I can upload an updated code snippet if necessary